# Integration on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable on $[0,1]$ such that $f(1)=f(0)=0$ and $\int_{0}^{1}[f(x)]^2dx=1.$ Prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)f^{'}(x)dx=\frac{-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Use integration by parts.

$$\int_0^1xf(x)f'(x)\,dx=\left.\frac{xf^2(x)}{2}\right|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{f^2(x)}{2}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{f^2(1)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Have a shot at integration by parts, using $u = x$ and $dv/dx = f'(x)f(x)$, and think about the chain rule for getting $v$.

---

As an independent note, you don't actually need $f(0) = 0$, merely that $f$ is well-defined at $0$ (so note $f(x) = 1/x$, for example); further, you don't actually need that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ or $1$, just that the integral is well-defined and $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$. Anyway, they're just technical details, for interest (if you find them interesting!). :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Smiley Sam. Thats what I was wondering, whats the use of giving the values of f(1) and f(0).

Comment: I mean, you **do** need $f(1) = 0$, as you need that (squared) to vanish in the integration by parts; however, you're already multiplying $f(0)$ by $0$, so it doesn't matter what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts you get the following: 
$$\int_0^1xf^{'}(x)f(x)dx=[xf^2(x)]_0^1-\int_0^1(f^{'}(x)x+f(x))f(x)dx  =[xf^2(x)]_0^1-\int_0^1(f^{'}(x)xf(x)dx -\int_0^1f^2(x)dx =[xf^2(x)]_0^1-\int_0^1(f^{'}(x)xf(x)dx -1$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$\int_0^1xf^{'}(x)f(x)dx=-\frac 12$$